# Implementing functional fold_right in Java

Tags: java, functional-programming

I'm trying to implement the functional method fold_right using some of Java's functional features. The code I have below works, but I don't really understand *why* it works - I think the main problem is that I'm a little bit uncertain about how lambdas work in Java (especially when using them with generics). For instance, why do I have to call the lambda I return in apply() by calling apply again? The class I'm taking is taught in OCaml, and it's easy for me to understand the fold_right function that OCaml has in its standard library. The way I implemented it in Java just seems so much more clunky and verbose - could someone maybe shed some light on this for me?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

interface Func<A,B> {
    B apply(A a);
}

class Add implements Func<Integer, Func<Integer,Integer>> {
    @Override
    public Func<Integer,Integer> apply(Integer a) {
        return (b) -> a + b;
    }
}

public class Fold {
    public static <E> E fold(Func<E,Func<E,E>> f, E acc, LinkedList<E> lst) {
        if (lst.isEmpty()) {
            return acc;
        } else {
            LinkedList<E> listClone = (LinkedList<E>) lst.clone();
            E theHead = listClone.removeFirst();
            return (E) f.apply(theHead).apply((fold(f,acc,listClone)));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] nums = {1,2,3,4,5};
        List<Integer> nums_lst = Arrays.asList(nums);
        LinkedList<Integer> lst = new LinkedList<Integer>(nums_lst);
        int result = Fold.fold(new Add(), 0, lst);
        System.out.println(result);  // should be 15
        System.out.println(lst);  // should be [1,2,3,4,5]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly off topic, but java has a built in [`Function<T, R>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html), that being said, to understand how the code works, let's start with the `Func<A, B>` interface:

```
interface Func<A,B> {
    B apply(A a);
}
```

So at a first glance, we have two types namely `A, B` and the `apply` method tells me that it takes in an argument of type `A` and returns an object of type `B`. Ok moving on to the `Add` class, this class implements the `Func` interface as:

```
Func<Integer, Func<Integer, Integer>>
```

So based on our previous reasoning, the `apply` method implemented in `Add` will take in an `Integer` and return a `Func<Integer, Integer>`. So when wee look at the `fold` method in side the `Fold` class: (you can think of `E` as `Object` for simplicity)

```
public static <E> E fold(Func<E,Func<E,E>> f, E acc, LinkedList<E> lst) {
    if (lst.isEmpty()) {
        return acc;
    } else {
        LinkedList<E> listClone = (LinkedList<E>) lst.clone();
        E theHead = listClone.removeFirst();
        //             A  B <- remember the Func interface? here A is E and B is Func<E,E>
        // f is a Func<E, Func<E, E>> that takes in an E and returns
        // another Func<E, E> after calling apply thus
        // breaking the steps:
        // f.apply(E) <- we just called the apply method thus this should return a "B"
        // Since B is a Func<E, E> we need to call apply to perform the operation
        // onto the next element, which in this case is an addition. You can think
        // of it as a -> b -> a + b. 
        // Now you played that nice trick of using recursion to call this function
        // and traverse all elements till the end of the collection and accumulate
        // all the intermediate results.
        return (E) f.apply(theHead).apply((fold(f,acc,listClone)));
        // the listClone is one element shorter in each recursion
        // since you are removing the first element
    }
}
```

On a side note, since your `Func<A, B>`, matches the signature of the `java.util.Function` you can pass the `Add` as a lambda without implementing the `Add` class explicilty:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] nums = {1,2,3,4,5};
    List<Integer> nums_lst = Arrays.asList(nums);
    LinkedList<Integer> lst = new LinkedList<Integer>(nums_lst);
    int result = Fold.fold(a -> b -> a + b, 0, lst);
    System.out.println(result);  // should be 15
    System.out.println(lst);  // should be [1,2,3,4,5]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot! The only thing I'm still confused about is when I do f.apply(theHead), since this returns a function, why can't I just call that function by adding an extra set of parens with the arguments? For example, if I implemented this in Python, if I have a function foo that returns another function, I can just do f(args)(other_args). Why is the lambda returned by apply called by calling apply again?

Comment: @rickyrichboy see in `Java` there's no free functions like in `python` so it doesn't really return a function but an `interface` instead. The `Func<>` that gets returned, is an `object` so you need to call `apply`. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Ohh I see. So is the lambda just automatically used as the implementation for apply? Is this because there’s only one method defined in the Func interface so the compiler just infers this?

Comment: @rickyrichboy Yep, the compiler is smart enough to figure out that `Func` looks like a function. As a matter of fact, you could change the name of `apply` to `test` and it will still recognize it as a function.

Comment: That’s kinda cool - would it not work if there were multiple methods in the interface?

Comment: @rickyrichboy  depends, see [functional interfaces](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/functional-interfaces-java/)